# Replacing field result with hook_views_pre_execute when replacing SQL query

Tags: views

I have a simple page view (unordered list) with just one field (content: path) and one contextual filter (nid). The view isn't displaying the right path if the language of the selected node is not the current site language.

For that reason i've decided to replace the query and try to get the aliased path of the selected node. I've used **hook_views_pre_execute** and already replaced the query for this view. The query already shows up in the preview section in Views UI but the result is empty now. The query works in phpmyadmin.

I can't find much documentation about this hook. How to get my query to replace the views **Path** field and display the result instead?

This is my SQL Query:

```
SELECT ua.alias AS alias
FROM 
{url_alias} ua
WHERE  (ua.source = 'node/247') 
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
```

This is my function from my custom module:

```
function views_node_path_views_pre_execute(&$view) {
 if($view->name == "global" && $view->current_display == "node_path_page") {
  $myQuery = db_select('url_alias', 'ua')
  ->condition('ua.source', 'node/' . $view->argument['nid']->value[0], '=')
  ->fields('ua', array('alias'));
  $view->build_info['query'] = $myQuery;
 }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Just fixed it myself with **hook_views_post_render** from views API. I know, it's just a dirty hack and i don't really like it but i need this part to be working.

```
function views_node_path_views_post_render(&$view, &$output, &$cache) {
 if($view->name == "global" && $view->current_display == "node_path_page") {
  $result = db_select('url_alias', 'ua')
   ->fields('ua', array('alias', 'language'))
   ->condition('ua.source', 'node/' . $view->argument['nid']->value[0], '=')
   ->execute()
   ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
  if($result) $output = '/' . $result[0][1] . '/' . $result[0][0];
 }
}
```

Comment: when you use post_render dont you get issues with the pagination being messed up?

Comment: maybe. i am only using this for node display with json output. so i don't have a pager there. but i think, it should be possible to get this working with a pager with a more advanced sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you are trying to display the aliased path of the current page using a view.If you are trying to encourage users to deep-link to your site, a [PHP code snippet](http://drupal.org/node/1861950) might be a better approach. (Drupal often encourages complex answers to simple requirements.)

Using aliased links means that the links may be broken if the alias changes (as with a change in the page title) unless the old aliases are retained. In that case, multiple aliases will exist for each page. Deep links should use the un-aliased url.

Comment: Thanks allot for your reply. I need those links to be displayed within a view. I am using views_datasource to get the results displayed with json output. Do you know how to replace SQL of a view?